# mysql import on Mac : second password asked?

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to import a mysql database from my Mac with terminal under OSX Yosemite. I typed the mysql command with -u -p -h etc but when I hit enter, Terminal ask me :
"Enter password".
I tried to re-enter the one I put in the command line, the one of my Mac, and others but nothing worked.
What is this second password asked ?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

For password options, the password value is optional.

If you use a -p or --password option and specify the password value, there must be no space between -p or --password= and the password following it.

If you use a -p or --password option but do not specify the password value, the client program prompts you to enter the password.

mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name

So if you typed -p passwd instead of -ppasswd, it will ask for the password.

If the password itself doesn't work, then you have it wrong.

Comment: OK. I see. In the other way I tried to import the file with
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h ... roger < roger.sql
but I only got
"Cant connect to local mysql server through socket mysql.sock"
What can I do please ?

Comment: This page shows the cause of the error and how to fix it.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/